# Are relations permitted with one's wife who does not safeguard Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shabbat, marriage, sexuality

One who transgresses Shabbos publicly has the status of a Gentile (Shulchan Aruch Y"D [2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.2.5?with=all&lang=bi) and [Shulchan Aruch Harav](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/ka5/2/10/index.htm) on it). Furthermore, Jews are forbidden from having relations with Gentiles.

That being the case, is it permissible for a man have relations with his wife who publicly does not safeguard Shabbos (despite having safeguarded Shabbos in the past)? Additionally, can she be trusted as regards the laws of *Niddah* (i.e. family purity)? (Can the husband assume that she did not have relations with another man, so she is not forbidden to him because of that?)

Any souces on the subject will be appreciated.

Comment: @lee thank you very much for editing my question (this applys even without anger)

Comment: It's important to clarify if this wife desecrates the shabbas publicly which makes things much worse,and does this person breaks shabbas l'hachis (does it with spite) or is it done l'teeavon (for.their enjoyment)

Comment: @sam i wrote publicly

Comment: @sam not l'hachis , (i do not think lihahis will make a difference)

Comment: Lhachis makes a diff according to the Ran in Chullin.

Comment: @sam l'teovon (but i do not think this will make a difference)

Comment: @sam please expound on this, (i do not know this Ran) and is it to halacha?

Comment: IMHO The question regarding *Niddah* should be submitted as a separate question.

Comment: @Lee B'havod i will +1 it b"n

Comment: The Ran discusses the idea that lhachis even for any aveirah one is considered a mumar,seems worse than a mechallel shabbas l'teeavon, but bit so clear there are alot of achronim that discuss this issue. Anyhow ,chillul shabbas is very specific because if one is embarrassed to do it confront of a Adam gadol they aren't considered a nochri,I am assuming that in your case it is someone who doesn't care,these little  specifics (details) are imp since the achronim have diff snif lahakel